# SSRS order by multiple criteria dropdown

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2005, reporting-services

Sorry for being a noob, but I believe this is the right place for the help I need.

I just started working on SSRS reports (2005) and I would like to find out how I can add a filter dropdown with multiple options that execute a sort. I have imported a list into my table and have the apropriate fields needed for this sort.

IE. I would like to have a dropdown box named "Sort By" with the available selections:

CustomerName

ZipCode, SIC

SIC, City

Each one of those performs the specific order by function that is selected when viewing the report.

I played around and was able to set datasets and add filters, but that isn't optimal because (for instance) you would have to know the exact ZipCode and SIC match to return any results.

There has to be an easy way to return this select statement with multiple order by criteria based on the selection of the dropdown list, but I can't find it if there is.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a couple of options. In both cases I've assumed a parameter SortOrder which contains the following values:

- CustomerName
- ZipCode, SIC
- SIC, City

**Apply sort expressions to Table based on Parameter**

I've applied to sorting expressions to the Table:

[image]

First sort:

```
=Switch(Parameters!SortOrder.Value = "CustomerName", Fields!CustomerName.Value
    , Parameters!SortOrder.Value = "ZipCode, SIC", Fields!ZIP.Value
    , Parameters!SortOrder.Value = "SIC, City", Fields!SIC.Value)
```

Second sort:

```
=Switch(Parameters!SortOrder.Value = "CustomerName", Fields!CustomerName.Value
    , Parameters!SortOrder.Value = "ZipCode, SIC", Fields!SIC.Value
    , Parameters!SortOrder.Value = "SIC, City", Fields!City.Value)
```

**Apply sort in query**

You can add an `order by` to your Dataset query based on the parameter to perform the same operation:

```
...
order by case @SortOrder when 'CustomerName' then CustomerName
  when 'ZipCode, SIC' then ZIP
  when 'SIC, City' then SIC
  end
  , case @SortOrder when 'CustomerName' then CustomerName
  when 'ZipCode, SIC' then SIC
  when 'SIC, City' then City
  end
```

In both cases you get a parameter-based sort:

[image]

[image]